# Options parameter in M AzureStorage.Blobs PowerQuery command

Tags: powerbi, azure-blob-storage, m

The [PowerQuery M command documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/azurestorage-blobs) documents hints for a second parameter of type record to pass `Options`. 
I tried a variety of keywords (such as `Prefix=sometext`), but all attempts resulted in a message that the option is not supported. Unfortunately I could not find any further reading on possible options … does anyone know?

```
AzureStorage.Blobs(**account** as text, optional **options* as nullable record) as table
```